# Date format in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have the date format coming as "19 May 2016", I want to write a condition if it's in that format , it should be converted as "19-May-16".
How do i do it in xslt.Would appreciate an quick answer.

Comment: I've flagged this for closing. This is a general question about XSLT, which belongs on Stack Overflow and not here. @Hulda.rachel - There are plenty of XSLT experts here but far more on stack overflow, so it's also more effective for you to ask it there.

Comment: I actually think this belongs on Tridion because we have specific helpers for this

Comment: It really does belong back on tridionstackexchange

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this is very easy to do in XSLT - although a bit verbose:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(date, ' ')"/>
<xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(date, ' '), ' ')"/>
<xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(substring-after(substring-after(date, ' '), ' '), 3, 2)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need an extension method for this, as doing it in XSLT is really hard. It is a long time since I used the XSLT mediator(s), and you don't state if you are using the one from the TBB Site, or the out of thebox one that comes with SDL Tridion 2013 and higher

Take a look at https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/xsltmediator.aspx and search for Date

and http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_8E74450486DE4950B81B3D83ACDDF5FA

The function to do this inside SDL is `<xsl:value-of select="mediator:GetFormattedDate('2012-10-08T06:30:00', 'MMMM dd, yyyy')" />`